# Log4j2 - setting log levels for a package and then a subpackage

Tags: java, apache, logging, log4j2

So, I wanted to have my own code at DEBUG, but Apache's at WARN. Except for Kafka, which generates too many warnings, so I tried this:

```
 log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,file
log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.common.config=ERROR

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p (%C) [%t] - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/my-app/application.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p (%C) [%t] - %m%n
```

The `log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN` line works. But `log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.common.config=ERROR` doen't seem to do anything, as I still get plenty of log statements like

> 2017-12-20T14:31:42.439 WARN (org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig) [main] - The configuration batch.size = 16384 was supplied but isn't a known config.

(The config warnings are due to a dependency, not my code, so cleaning the config file is out of my control.)

I tried reversing the order:
    log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.common.config=ERROR
    log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
but that had no effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also run into that issue... Problem there what `org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig` is abstract class! So really that never has instances for log. And you need to configure logging by concrete ancestors.
For example (there should be most, but some other may be added in feature versions):

```
log4j.logger.io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverterConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.io.confluent.ksql.logging.processing.ProcessingLogConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroDataConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TaskConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverterConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceConnectorConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceConnectorConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTaskConfig=ERROR
```

Comment: Thanks! Glad it wasn't just me :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing the additivity config on the logger.

This will prevent the incoming logger from propagating to its parent logger.

```
log4j.additivity.org.apache.kafka.common.config=false
```

more information can be found [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) and [here](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-additivity-what-and-why/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This certainly seems like the correct answer but it still isn't working.